# Use python DIctionary key values in html email

Tags: html, python-2.7, email, dictionary

I have a python dictionary with 100+ key/value pairs.

In my python script I am writing an email with HTML all this works fine but once I import the dictionary and need both value and keys thats where I require assistancve.
however I need to iterate all items in the dictionary into the HTML message.

the dictionary is {email address : unique link}
I cannot figure out how to get this to work

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText


list_dict = {"email@domain.com" : "https://unique link goes here"}

for key, value in list_dict.items():

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

    msg['From'] = 'user@domain.com'
    msg['To'] = "Message Goes Here"
    msg['Subject'] = 'Message Goes Here'

    html= """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p>Good morning,<br>
           <br>
           message goes here. Please <a href={}.format(value)>Click Here</a> to begin. 
        </p>
        <p>

      </body>
    </html>
    """

    part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('emailserver',port)

    mailserver.ehlo()

    mailserver.starttls()

    mailserver.ehlo()


    mailserver.sendmail("senders email@domain.com",{}.format(key), msg.as_string())
```

Comment: I think it would be better to make a function that accepts a `dict` and then returns the new string as an output, instead of using a for loop.

Comment: can you provide an example?